# Paladin archer looking to combat optimize my 9th level choices

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, paladin

I am looking for any good point to improve my character. I'd like to be the "rock star" among my companions. This is my first character what i made. I already looked in all known guides: Bodhi's, Cryptic's, Deadeye's Servant, Thallin's, ...

My companions are a *Cleric* and a *Fighter*.

The fighter's primary role is to beat weak creatures and to keep away strong ones from us. He is using two kukris (using the weapon finesse feat) or one kukri with a heavy shield. He can have around 28-30 AC. So he is primarily a **damage dealer** and secondary a "**tank**".

The cleric usually tries to save(like cure *** wounds etc.) us. If he isn't doing that, he often uses Divine Power spell to kick out our enemies. He has Impaler of Thorns to do this job well. He is primary a "nuker" and secondary a healer(support). Both players have level 8 characters.

And finally I usually cast Bless and/or Bless Weapon (on the fighter) before an encounter from wands. When a situation requires, I use weapon bond, lay on hands class ability, and the Divine Favor (one reason of Fate's Favored trait) spell which I prepare 3 per day. I use a Wand of Cure Light Wounds to fulfill our healing after combat needs.

In combat, I try to beat evil creatures as soon as possible via application of DPS.

## My character

**Name**: Dranko
**Alignment**: Lawful good
**Race**: Human
**Hit Dice**: 8
**Class**: Level 8 Paladin
**Deity**: Iomedae

**Point to buy attributes**: 15
**Attributes**:

Attribut | stat | bonus | point to buy
Strength | 12 | +1 | 2
Dexterity | 16 | +5 | 10
Constitution | 8 | -1 | -2
Inteligence | 10 | +0 | 1
Wisdom | 8 | -1 | -2
Charisma | 15 | +4 | 7

2+10-2+0-2+7=15

#### [Statistics]

(with bonus from items, race, lvl points):

[Strenght] | 14 | +2 (Belt of Giant Strength +2)
[Dexterity] | 20 | +5 (Snakeskin Tunic (Dex +2), race)
[Constitution] | 8 | -1
[Inteligence] | 13 | +1 (Ring of Vast Intelligence +2, lvl point)
[Wisdom] | 8 | -1
[Charisma] | 18 | +4 (Headband of alluring charisma +2, lvl point)

#### [Feats]

- [1] Point-Blank Shot (Bonus Human Feat)
- [1] Deadly Aim
- [3] Precise shot
- [5] Rapid Shot
- [7] Manyshot

#### [Saves]

Save | Base | mod | misc. | total

Fortitute | 6 | -1 | 5 | 10

Reflex | 2 | 5 | 5 | 12

Will | 6 | -1 | 5 | 10

#### [Archetypes]

- Oath of Vengeance

#### [Traits]

- Magical Knack - +2 caster level to one spellcasting class up to your HD.
- Fate's Favored - Whenever you are under the effect of a luck bonus of any kind, that bonus increases by 1.

#### [Items]

- Snakeskin Tunic
- Efficient Quiver
- Belt of giant strength +2
- Headband of Alluring Charisma +2
- Composite Bow +2 (+1magic)
- Ring of Vast Intelligence +2
- Cloak of resistance +1
- Boots of Levitate

Its cost is about 30 000 golds together. I gather items this during 8 level progressing.

#### [Skills]

- Perception, Diplomacy, Use Magical Device [8 points]
- Acrobatics [5 points]
- Spellcraft, Sense Motive, Ride, Knowledge(religion, nobility, planes, nature, arcana), Heal, Handle Animal, Disable Device [1 point]

#### [What is my idea]

My idea is at 9 level, get feat Unsanctioned Knowledge. Problem is that I am very hesitant... I cant decide what should I pick. Here is the list of my ideas...

- [1] Unseen Servant/Expeditious Retreat
- [2] Heroism
- [3] Haste/Channel Vigor
- [4] Greater invisibility/Echolocation/Stoneskin/Divine Power

I looked for long duration buffs, that improve my combat skills or spells that complete our shortcomings.

Next plan is to get some useful feats like Clustered Shot[11], Weapon Focus[13]. After that maybe Shatter Defenses[15] + Dazzling Display[17], Steadfast Personality[15](Self Delusion [17]).

Sadly, we usualy don't get a lot of money. So I write my item wish list....

-better enchants for composite longbow,
-Pearl of Power to extend first(or higher) level slot,
-Mithtil breastplate +2 or more,
-Bracers of Archery,
-Headband of Mental Superiority to save some item slots,
-lot of scrolls to keep situational divine spells (for instance Endure Elements, Undetectable Alignment, Zone of Truth, etc...)

### [My Questions]

My questions are mainly focused on my future 9 level. Books: Core, APG, UC, UM, ISWG

- Is there any way to improve my combat skills more (attack rolls primarily) with my 9th level choices?
- Which paladin spells should I prepare every day?

I have a separate question about what spells to take from Unsanctioned Knowledge: [Unsanctioned Knowledge, best combat buffs for a paladin and small party?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/unsanctioned-knowledge-what-is-the-good-best-spells)

Comment: OK, I think given you're this 8th level character and want guidance on options to take for your 9th and what spells you should have as a combat buff centric loadout, I'll open this (probably best to keep your other UK question focusing on that.)

Answer (score 2):

**The best way that I can see you improving your combat effectiveness is through the specific spells you choose.**

As you had said, money is sort of tight in your campaign, so you need to make due with what you have at your disposal naturally. Luckily, this isn't hard considering that you have a +4 Cha score (Giving you anywhere between 1-4 additional spells per day **at your current bonus**). So considering your want to improve how well you do in combat, **focus on preparing combat buff spells**

These are the spells that I think you should prioritize (keep in mind that I only have the core rule book on hand):

+**Bless Weapon(1st):** A very situational buff, but powerful when used against the right enemies (ya did good on this one)

+**Magic Weapon(1st):** Prepare this instead of Bless. Bless may give you a bonus against fear, but Magic Weapon increases your damage as well as your attack bonus.

+**Bull's Strength(2nd):** I know that you put most of your stuff into Ranged Weapons, but everything on the list available to me is either a buff you don't need or something that seams too underhanded for a "rock star" (also, I don't think you need a spell that lets you take half of the damage that your friends take when there is a fully-functioning tank). As you may already know, Bull's Strength increases your Strength Ability by 4, so at the very least, you increase your Combat Maneuver Scores. This means it's easier to absolutely wreak an enemy's day by affecting how they move, inflicting statuses on them, or simply moving through them.

+**Greater Magic Weapon(3rd):** THIS is one of the key spells you should prepare when you get into the upper echelons. It's like Magic Weapon, but it gives you additional bonus amounts for every four levels your character has. Also, this spell specifically states that you can cast this spell on up to 50 arrows in the same quiver; this means that if you have to switch to another bow, or if your party also invests in bows, the spell is used to its maximum potential between multiple weapons.

+**Prayer(3rd):** Anyone in a 40ft radius of you receives a +/-1 to every roll depending on their loyalties; That's an increased advantage of 2 against whatever enemies you are fighting!

+**Dispel Chaos/Evil(4th):** these two spells give you +4 against the attacks of the designated alignment and automatically dispels effects cast by said creatures or spells that are of that alignment

**This last one is just in case you attempt to build physically or your Fighter is being cornered by a Demon or something...**

-**Holy Sword:** *PROS:* weapon automatically becomes +5 AND deals an additional 2d6 damage to Evil Creatures. *CONS:* Can only be applied to melee weapons and negates the powers of whatever weapon it is used on (that last bit could be fun to use against an enemy using an all-powerful cursed weapon, but again, this is a bit situational)

I hope this helps.

P.S.: Your party should invest in Heavy Repeating Crossbows once you hit level 10[image: heyo]
<sub>(source: [threadbombing.com](https://www.threadbombing.com/data/media/2/Pred_Jung_02.gif))</sub>

[See Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125215921/http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/crossbow-repeating)