# Unsanctioned Knowledge, best combat buffs for a paladin and small party?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

I have a 8th level Oath of Vengeance Paladin (see [Paladin archer looking to combat optimize my 9th level choices](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71300/iomedaes-chosen-one-is-there-better-way-to-shoot-down-a-lot-of-enemies)) who specializes in ranged attacks. I'm interested in buffing myself or others, and I'm primarily looking for long term duration spells like Heroism.

I'm taking the feat [Unsanctioned Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/unsanctioned-knowledge) — what level 1-4 spells should I pick from the cleric/oracle/inquisitor/bard spell lists that would be the best combat buffs?

My companions are a Weapon Finesse Fighter who always fights with kukri, and a cleric who often uses divine power and Impaler of Thorns.

Comment: I think this is now focused enough - cherrypicking combat buff spells off the UK lists for a 9th level archer pally and two friends.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

Gravity Bow for yourself or Lead Blades for friends; Upping the effective size of your weapons is always nice for a level 1 spell, and it becomes even more dramatic if you have enlarge person or oversized weapons in the party

Protection from Energy, Communal; it can soak up some splash damage if that's a common issue you expect to fight

Ice Slick, to grease an area and knock up to four medium sized enemies prone might be okay if you don't mind them taking the +4 AC bonus to you specifically, but it will help your friends out and depending on the terrain could last indefinitely

Sound Burst for potential to stun a 2x2 area is also to be considered, if you're looking at more area-of-effect debuffs and Ice Slick doesn't work for you

Ironskin, because natural armor is powerful and you might get caught alone or just by a stray bolt

Carry Companion, if you expect casualties, travel issues, etc.

Summon Nature's Ally 1-4 for some reinforcements and to keep people off of you and your friends; some of the creatures summoned have some potentially useful abilities, like Constrictor or Venomous snakes and Crocodiles.

Named Bullet, to give your bow (And other's projectiles) the ability to strike against touch AC

and finally, Bow Spirit, so you can free yourself up to do other things and still get some damage in, or just get a bonus attack at your full BAB.

Comment: Lead Blades is Ranger only, which is not one of the available spell lists. Same with Gravity Bow.

Comment: Not a factor.

-Ring of Spell Knowledge is a low-cost item that provides access. 

-Mystic Past Life of the Samsarans allows access, as well.

-Considering Oracle Mysteries, you can gain the Metal mystery, granting Lead Blades. This can be done by Variant Multi-classing.

-Unsanctioned Knowledge grants Gravity Bow access.

-Researching a new spell, costing 1,000 GP; to quote core rule-book: 
"Independent Research: A divine spellcaster can also research a spell independently, much as an arcane spellcaster can."

Comment: If you can do Independent Research, why even bother with the Feat? The point of the question was for choices to use with the Feat Unsanctioned Knowledge. If you're giving access to those spells from some other source, then they are bad choices for the feat.

Answer (score -1):

Thankfully I happen to be sitting across from a friend who habitually builds Unsanctioned Knowledge Paladins. These are all pretty subjective and we play in a highly competitive setting, but here is a short list at his suggestion. His recommendation was that Bard Spells are probably your best place to look, they get a lot of unique spells and good mass buffs.

Bard lvl 1

- Moment of Greatness
- Grease (good battlefield control)

lvl 2

- Invisibility
- Blur
- Mirror Image

lvl 3

- Good Hope (Bard-only spell, really good buff)
- Haste (if you don't already have Blessing of Fervor)

lvl 4

- Greater Invisibility
- Shadow Conjuration (mimics a Conjuration spell under lvl 4)
- Dimension Door (Along with the Dimensional Agility feats = hilarity)

Comment: For this to work as an answer, there really needs to be an explanation as to why these selections meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: "I'm interested in buffing myself or others, and I'm primarily looking for long term duration spells like Heroism." There's not a single long-term buff on your list.